# Invalid dimension or metric

Tags: php, regex, analytics, google-analytics-api

im trying to filter where the ID appears in the URL Ive tried the following but with no luck any help is appreciated

```
GDatabadRequestInvalid dimension or metric: ga:pagePath=~14042[^0-9]*"'
```

Comment: And... what's the URL?

Comment: /hoteles/14042-0_hotel-tenuta-la-bandita

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add this URL and detail your issue: what you want to do (what's "filter where the ID appears"?), what you expected your code to do, why it's not working?

Comment: Have you tried testing it in http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?  could you post your full request ga:pagePath is a valid dimension so I don't understand why you would be getting invalid dimension or metric error.